# On app startup Attached Property Callback Event return null for a Control property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

**Story & Problem:**

I create `IsActivated` property as an Attached Property to be able to add it to any control in XAML page I want. Then when any control set it to `true`, I want `PropertyChangedCallback` event fired and examine binding of specific `Property` of that control. The app is running without any problem, also all controls with setting `IsActivated` property to `true` will fired that event and binding object show the value correctly in UI too.

**But the problem is**, When `PropertyChangedcallback` event executing, `GetBinding()` or `GetBindingExpression()` methods will return `null` value for those `Properties`.

(*For now I only Check on `TextBox` and on its `TextProperty`*)

**Background & What I already tried**

I used the same technique in my production applications, But when I try to simplify it to demonstrate it to a friend, It is not working!

I find out, if I Set/Change `IsActivated` property for a `TextBox` at `MainWindow.OnLoaded()` event, Then in its Callback event it will correctly return binding info for `TextBox.TextProperty`:

```cs
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBox.SetValue(ChangeBehavior.IsActivatedProperty, false);
}
```

but I did not do this in my real apps and I do not like this solution!

**Source Codes**

This is [GitHub](https://github.com/MrkTheCoder/WpfApp-AttachedProperty-Examine-Controls-Property-Bindings) full sample codes.

But here is my Attached Property class:

```cs
public static class ChangeBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActivatedProperty;

    static ChangeBehavior()
    {
        IsActivatedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
            (
                "IsActivated",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(ChangeBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsActivatedPropertyChangedCallback)
            );
    }

    public static bool GetIsActivated(DependencyObject obj)
        => (bool)obj.GetValue(IsActivatedProperty);
    public static void SetIsActivated(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        => obj.SetValue(IsActivatedProperty, value);

    private static void OnIsActivatedPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is TextBox)) return;
        
        // ===> Here I get null value
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(d, TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (binding == null) return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            var sourceObject = binding.Path.Path;
            //Doing some stuff...
        }
        else
        {
            //Doing some stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my UI XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="MyTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Model.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             local:ChangeBehavior.IsActivated="True"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow Code-Behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel class: (Omit NotifyProperty... parts to make it shorter)

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Model = new Model {Name = "Model One"};
    }

    public Model Model
    {
        get => _model;
        set
        {
            _model = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEvent...
}
```

Model class: (Omit NotifyProperty... parts to make it shorter)

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEvent...
    }
}
```

**What's wrong with my code!**

I expect when `InitializeComponent();` execute from my `MainWindow` constructor (just like my real app) any control that set `local:ChangeBehavior.IsActivated` to `true` in XAML, I get correct bindig info of their `Properties` at `OnIsActivatedPropertyChangedCallback` method!

Why almost the same technique (and almost the same code!) work in my real applications, but it doesn't work in this simple code!?

What I am missing here!?

**Updated: Second way to Fix my problem is:**

Instead of using my `IsAttached` Property Directly on an Element, I should use it in a ResourceDictionary. (The other way is that I marked as answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to see where this is being used in your real projects. In this one, it's getting set before the binding is set on `Text`. Never let attached properties depend on order of initialization, because that's totally out of your control.

What we want to do is: If we can do it, do it. If not, do it after the control is loaded, unless it's already loaded, in which case there's almost certainly not going to be anything to do. It's OK to do it in a Loaded handler here because a) consumers of the class don't have to look at it, and b) you have no other choice.

We ideally would like to do this whenever a binding is set on `Text`, but there's no event for that, and it's relatively uncommon for bindings to be replaced at runtime.

```
private static void OnIsActivatedPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (!tryGetBinding() && !textBox.IsLoaded)
        {
            void onLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e2)
            {
                tryGetBinding();

                textBox.Loaded -= onLoaded;
            };

            textBox.Loaded += onLoaded;
        }

        bool tryGetBinding()
        {
            // ===> Here I get null value
            var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty);

            if (binding == null)
                return false;

            if (GetIsActivated(textBox))
            {
                var sourceObject = binding.Path.Path;
                //Doing some stuff...
            }
            else
            {
                //Doing some stuff...
            }

            return true;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That is working great!! I am still wondering why It is working without this `Loaded()` event in my apps!? While It was not working here!? I learn this technique  from this tutorial **Pluralsight: WPF and MVVM: Advanced Model Treatment** by @ThomasClaudiusHuber . We used `DI` to inject ViewModels there & can it the reason that is working there!!? anyway I am sure It is my fault due to be bad student for Thomas! lool But your solution is great. I was try to find the reason for hours & ... you saved me!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MRK I got that queasy feeling when I saw your window had a constructor parameter there'd be something weird with viewmodels going on. Well, it's your life. I'd really like to see a context where it *did* work the old way. Was it in a DataTemplate perhaps?

Comment: I found Thomas Code on GitHub, here you can examine his full code: https://github.com/StevenGodin/pluralsight-FriendStorage , We define IsActive in a `ResourceDictionary` placed at `FriendStorage.UI\Styles\ControlBaseStyle.cs`.  Also you can check this folder: `FriendStorage.UI\Behavior\ChangeBehavior` and  this is the original file that I try to simplify it and I failed! **Now you have the full sample** Could you Please do me another favor!? If you find why `IsActive` AttachedProperty of Thomas code is working while he did not use `Load()` event, please tell me too! Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: Thanks for Style tip! You are right, and I test it with Style too and it worked! Thank you so much for your time, I learned new things today from you, as I learned many things from Thomas Tutorials. I am sure all faults are on me here ;) [Bad Student!] Thank you again & have great time...

Comment: @MRK Quite seriously, he should have known this would be an issue. He “taught” you something wrong.

Comment: Could you point me to a good WPF book !? I Read `Pro WPF 4.5 in C#` from Apress, It was a great book, While it was great startup WPF book, It didn't go in deep of things like `Dependency Properties` or `Attached Properties` with some practical samples.

Comment: @MRK I’ve never read a WPF book, sadly. I taught myself on the job and by answering Stack Overflow questions. Not the quickest way, I’m afraid.

Comment: Sorry, I try to get to binding object (I need its Type and not it's Object) from inside the `if (GetIsActivated(textBox))` statement & that is `Model`.  I try to get `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression()` instead of `GetBinding()` method so I can access `ResolvedSource` of `BindingExpression`. But now `ResolvedSource` is returning `null` value!!? How can I access the Object or its Type !? I know the `binding.Path.Path' give me both Object and Property name, but without knowing object namespace I cannot use `Type.GetType("namespace.ClassName")` too!

Comment: @MRK Why are you doing any of this? It’s fairly exotic stuff. What problem are you solving with it? Your time would be infinitely better spent learning MVVM.

Comment: I have a `ModelWrapperBase` class, I wrap my Entity classes and add two properties for each property inside that class with same name plus `xxxIsChanged` & `xxxOriginalValue`then in my XAML pages I add `isActivated` attached property to each Control that binding to main property of that class and in Callback event method I add other two properties binding to that Control automatically. Sometimes, some properties do not have those two extra properties, I wanna examine the Class to see if that is a case, then bypass that process.

Comment: I am using MVVM!

Comment: If your model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you’re doing MVVM wrong. I suppose this tutorial guy had that idea? You still haven’t told me what problem you’re trying to solve with all this code. Is it a way to maintain an IsDirty flag or something?

Comment: lol I guess if you find Thomas! (that guy!) you will kill him! anyway, Please check this: https://github.com/StevenGodin/pluralsight-FriendStorage/blob/master/FriendStorage.UI/Behaviors/ChangeBehavior.cs inside this method `OnIsActivePropertyChanged` we define two new binding for a Control, what I need is to be able to find out what is the type of Object or Object itself . (But `ResolvedSource` return `null` unfortunately)

Comment: If user change data in a Control, then xxxIsChanged will set to True then some triggers will change the Styles of that Control.(like different Background and ...)  Also a Tooltip for the Control will show the original data. Original data will retrieve from xxxOriginalValue property.